# How can I fix my dash not working properly when jumping and how can I add a cooldown?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Recently I have been Frankensteining code I've found online together and I am struggling to implement the dash correctly.  In its current state, whenever my character jumps and then uses his dash, he gets caught in the air as if the dash didn't move him. Obviously this inst intended and I was wondering how I could fix this. Also, how could I include a cool down system to my dash ability. I've tried using various sources for cool down scripts but they always seem to have a downside.
Thanks in advance!

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using UnityEngine;

public class CharacterController : MonoBehaviour
{
    //Player Movement
    public float speed;
    public float jumpForce;
    public Transform feetPos;
    public float checkRadius;
    public LayerMask whatIsGround;
    public float dashSpeed;
    public float startDashTime;
    
    private float timeStamp = 0;

    public Animator animator;

    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    private float moveInput;
    private bool isGrounded;
    private float jumpTimeCounter;
    public float jumpTime;
    private bool isJumping;
    private float dashTime;
    public int direction;
    
    void Start()
    {
        animator.GetComponent<Animator>();
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        dashTime = startDashTime;
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        moveInput = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        if (direction < 1)
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(moveInput * speed, rb.velocity.y);
    }
    void Update()
    {
        // Moving
        isGrounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(feetPos.position, checkRadius, whatIsGround);

        if (moveInput > 0)
        {
            transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
            animator.SetBool("Moving", true);
        }
        else if (moveInput < 0)
        {
            transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 180, 0);
            animator.SetBool("Moving", true);
        }
        else
        {
            animator.SetBool("Moving", false);
        }
        // Jumping
        if (isGrounded == true && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            animator.SetTrigger("IsJumping");
            isJumping = true;
            jumpTimeCounter = jumpTime;
            rb.velocity = Vector2.up * jumpForce;
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space) && isJumping == true)
        {
            if (jumpTimeCounter > 0)
            {
                rb.velocity = Vector2.up * jumpForce;
                jumpTimeCounter -= Time.deltaTime;
            }
            else
            {
                isJumping = false;
            }
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            isJumping = false;
        }
        if (isGrounded == false)
        {
            animator.SetBool("Grounded", false);
        }
        if (isGrounded == true)
        {
            animator.SetBool("Grounded", true);
        }
    
        // Dashing
        if (direction == 0)
        {
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftShift))
            {
                if ((transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y == 180))
                {
                    Dashleft();
                }
                else
                {
                    DashRight();
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (dashTime <= 0)
            {
                direction = 0;
                dashTime = startDashTime;
                rb.velocity = Vector2.zero;
            }
            else
            {
                dashTime -= Time.deltaTime;
            }
        }
        void Dashleft()
        {
            direction = 1;
            rb.velocity = Vector2.left * dashSpeed;
        }
        void DashRight()
        {
            direction = 1;
            rb.velocity = Vector2.right * dashSpeed;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `startDashTime`?

Comment: ```startDashTime``` determines the amount of time that the dash will go on for.

Comment: Yes, I understand this, but I don't see anywhere in your code `startDashTime = ...;` so if you do not set it anywhere, its value will be `0` and I don't really see how you expect it to work then

Comment: Its public so I determine the value in the inspector. Normally its 0.2

Comment: Ok so the first frame when you dash, you set `rb.velocity = Vector2.[left/right] * dashspeed`, but the next frame, you enter the jump block and set it back to `rb.velocity = Vector2.up * jumpForce` so you are only "dashing" for 1 frame (you are not dashing anymore because you set `direction = 1` the first time, so you do not enter `if(direction == 0)` the second time)

Comment: Would you happen to know how I could rearrange my code to fix this, sorry, I'm quite new to programming!

Comment: Well, first, I'd remove the `if(direction == 0)` or the `direction = 1` inside your `Dash[left/right]` functions because one shouldn't prevent the other. Then I would only set the horizontal value of the `velocity` vector inside those functions, because I don't think that you want to cancel the "up" movement from your jump on dashing (same for your jump, set only the vertical value of the vector, because I suspect that right now when you jump, your character is only moving up and down (not left & right)